# Finding moment of Inertia of area bounded by a polar equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, moment-of-inertia

I have to find Moment of Inertia of area bounded by curve $r^2 = a^2 \cos{2 \Theta}$

Since I already know the shape of given curve, I can easily take an element area and double integrate using suitable values of $r$ and $\Theta$.

But is there any general method to follow, say in an examination, when I don't know what the curve of given polar equation looks like? Finding $r$ values corresponding to specific $\Theta$ seems time consuming.

Or, does there exist any method for finding Moment of Inertia which does not require plotting of curve?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Does the plot help: [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolarPlot%5BSqrt%5BCos%5B2+%5C%5BTheta%5D%5D%5D,+%7B%5C%5BTheta%5D,+0,+2+%5C%5BPi%5D%7D%5D) ?

Comment: I know how the curve looks like. I am trying to figure out how to approach problems, say in an examination, where I am given a $r$ and $\Theta$ relation but don't know how it looks like. I am assuming knowing the curve is a necessity for calculating Moment of Inertia. @secavara does that make it clear ?

Comment: Have you looked at, for instance, [the Wikipedia entry on MoI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia)? Or any other resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your density is $\rho$, the moment of inertia is

$$I=\int \rho r^2 dA$$

For polar coordinates, $dA=r\;dr\;d\theta$, so

$$I=\int \rho r^3 dr\; d\theta$$

Your boundary is defined as a polar function $r=f(\theta)$, which determines the limit of the $r$ integral:

$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{f(\theta)}\rho r^3 dr\; d\theta$$

Simplifying the $r$ integral:

$$I=\frac{\rho}{4}\int_0^{2\pi}f(\theta)^4d\theta$$

which is the simplest general formula for an arbitrary boundary.